# Possible to establish Ipsec connection when configure with different aes encryption bit size

Tags: linux, encryption, vpn, daemon, ipsec

I want to setup ipsec in my network, for that i am using racoon in linux devices. If i configure racoon with 2 different PC with different aes encryption will establish connection ?

*for eg. If PC-A racoon configured with aes128 encryption and PC-B with AES_-256 encryption, is it possible to establish connection between PC-A and PC-B? or it will establish connection only when both encryption are same (eg. both use aes256)*

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same encryption algorithm supported on both ends of the tunnel.

In cases where you need to have different algorithms in your environment, you can configure your systems to support several algorithms. The two peers will negotiate which to use.

If the peers are unable to negotiate common algorithms, the tunnel setup will fail with an error message, like "no proposal chosen" or similar, (I am not sure which message Racoon will throw).

Comment: thank you for your reply,

Comment: thank you for your reply,   In my racoon one device use aes 128 and another device use aes 256 surprisingly both established connection. i don't know why that happens.